# How to use AddDbContextPool with getting DbContextOptions from DI

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dependency-injection

For the now we are using approach with injecting DbContextOptions as scoped and Context as transient lifetime:

```
        private void AddDal(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            if (WithDal)
            {
                services.AddScoped(provider => DatabaseHelper.CreateDbContextOptions(Configuration, provider));
                services.WithCommonDal();
            }
        }
...
serviceCollection
                .AddTransient<PersonsContext>()
```

How I can replace transient context to `AddDbContextPool<PersonsContext>(???)`
with getting options from di?

p.s. PersonsContext has default ctor -

```
public PersonsContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{}
```

Comment: Please read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant#managing-state-in-pooled-contexts

Comment: Im not sure, how does it can help me?

Comment: What's the question? DbContexts aren't transient nor are they registered directly. Did you check the [DbContext pooling docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant#dbcontext-pooling)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way how I able to resolved it:

```
.AddDbContextPool<PersonsContext>((serviceProvider, opt) => opt.CreateDbContextOptions(configuration, serviceProvider))
```

and helper

```
public static DbContextOptions CreateDbContextOptions(this DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilder, IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
{return dbContextOptionsBuilder... .Options}
```

Comment: The real answer is [do what the docs show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant#dbcontext-pooling). That's what Gert Arnold said 1 week ago